# How can I install torchtext?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp

I have PyTorch installed in my machine but whenever I try to do the following-

```
from torchtext import data
from torchtext import datasets
```

I get the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'torchtext'
```

How can I install torchtext?

Comment: I'd like a version of torchtext (and pytorch) compatible with `cuda>=11.0`

Comment: perhaps useful: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-one-install-a-torchtext-version-compatible-with-cuda-11-0/132276

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69229975/how-does-one-install-torchtext-with-cuda-11-0-and-pytorch-1-9 for cuda 11.0 or above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package was released with setuptools support. You can clone the [repository](https://github.com/pytorch/text) and run `python setup.py install`. Unfortunately, I don't think that they have released it on pip.

Comment: I think they may have released it on the pip index now: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/torchtext/0.1.1

Answer (score 19):

[As stated in the PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/install-torchtext/8328), simply do:

```
$ pip install https://github.com/pytorch/text/archive/master.zip
```

That should do it.

---

If not, as an alternative, try:

```
$ pip install torchtext
```

---

For more advanced options, dependencies, and customized installations see:

[pypi.org/project/torchtext](https://pypi.org/project/torchtext)

Comment: where is the link to the pytorch forum?

Comment: @CharlieParker see updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

I am using conda and succeeded with

```
conda install -c pytorch torchtext
```

Comment: Reference: [Skusu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5407040/skusku) suggested this in their comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55081539/623735) in 2019. This is what I do as well.

Comment: Worked for me in November, 2021

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
pip install torchtext
```

For more details on installation please read [pytorch github](https://github.com/pytorch/text)

Comment: Doesn't work with pytorch0.4. The answer by kmario23 is better untill they update pip release.

Answer (score 2):

I got the import statements to work after i ran these commands:

```
conda create --name test5 python=3.6
conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision cpuonly torchtext
python
>>> from torchtext import data
>>> from torchtext import datasets
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using conda, you can run

```
    conda install -c derickl torchtext
```

as per https://anaconda.org/derickl/torchtext

Comment: This did not work for me. 
Going to anaconda.org and searching for torchtext revealed:

https://anaconda.org/pytorch/torchtext

which states that one should use:
conda install -c pytorch torchtext

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/pytorch/text
```

I used it to ugrade on google colab

Answer (score 0):

Try this command it fixed the problem for me:
`pip install torchtext==0.4`